# SFDX - Cannot find messages folder on npm run prepack

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

In my environment we cannot use yarn to do a prepack on a custom dx plugin. So, we are trying to do the equivalent of **yarn prepack** with **npm run prepack**

In the latter case, the typescript compiler continues to fail saying

```
MissingBundleError Plugin: @mynpmscope/myplugin: Missing bundle myplugin:mycommand for local en_US
```

I've tried to change my prepack script to create a **lib** folder and recursively copy the JSON files to a new **messages** subfolder under **lib**

My prepack script: `"prepack": "rimraf lib && mkdir lib && cp -R ./messages ./lib/messages && tsc -b && oclif-dev manifest && oclif-dev readme"`

but still it fails. Is there a change I need to make in my package.json in order for the compiler to look elsewhere? Maybe the `files` section of the JSON?

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub page details the issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate/issues/59

In my case, I still had the old name without the scope as the first argument in each `Messages.loadMessage()`, so `Messages.loadMessage('myplugin','myhelpfile')` instead of `Messages.loadMessage('@mynpmscope/myplugin','myhelpfile')`